# AIR Get hash value on LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGING from StageWebView

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air, stagewebview

I am building an HTML-based AIR app and in order to invoke ActionScript methods, I append hash tags on the HTML app's URL with specific patterns (#AIRBRIDGE_methodName_arguments). Using window.location = '#AIRBRIDGE_methodName_arguments'; in the JavaScript of the HTML app invokes the AIR LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGING event, but when I try to access the StageWebView.location value the hash is not returned.

Has anyone had experience with this? Here is the ActionScript code:

```
public function LoadHtmlPageByName(pageName:String, stage:Stage):void
    {
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;

        webView = new StageWebView(); 
        webView.stage = stage;
        webView.addEventListener(LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGING, onLocationChange);
        webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);

        var htmlPath:String = new File(new File("app:/assets/html/" +  pageName + "#something").nativePath).url;
        webView.loadURL(htmlPath);
    }

    public function onLocationChange(event:LocationChangeEvent):void
    {
        trace("you are now at: ", webView.location);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of # (hash anchoring), use an unknown protocol for window.location.

Example:  window.location="unknown:/and_add_here_your_method_info".

Adobe Air can trap that through LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGE or LOCATION_CHANGING.

Notes for iOS:
    Also listen to EventError.Error.  In my case using Adobe Air 3.4, the value of window.location is being passed to EventError.text.  So also check on that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess 'location' will not change if you page is not reloaded.
You can try to change and read title of the page, but I'm not sure it will change if page is not reloaded.